# How do I populate a JavaFX ChoiceBox with data from the Database?

Tags: java, javafx

```
private void initialize() {
    loadPersistenceContext();

    List<Events> events = getEventsChoiceBox(getPersistenceContext());
    ObservableList<Event> data = FXCollections.observableList(events);

    cbEvent.setItems(data); // Inserting data into the ChoiceBox
}
```

This is my main code. Problem is when the form is loaded, I get the Objects inserted in the ChoiceBox and not the properties.

This is the content of my List Events

```
Object[]
|- String
|- Integer
Object[]
|- String
|- Integer
```

So I want a ChoiceBox with that String property showing up and the Integer mapped to my controller.

I tried a lot of things but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I find it a bit difficult to understand your question, but see if this [example of a JavaFX ChoiceBox control backed by Database IDs](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1422104) helps as it seems to solve a somewhat similar problem to what you are asking.

Comment: I know it was a bit confusing cuz I didn't knew how to express this clearly but the example helped a lot! thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this example of a [JavaFX ChoiceBox control backed by Database IDs](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1422104).

The example works by defining a Choice class consisting of a database row ID and a string representation of the item to be displayed in the Choice box.  The default `toString` method of Choice is overridden with a custom implementation that returns a string representation of the item to be displayed and not the database ID.  When you add the choices to the ChoiceBox, the ChoiceBox will convert each Choice into a string for display.  The displayed string value of the Choice is just the choice text rather than also including the database ID or using the default `toString` of Choice that would just display a meaningless object reference.

Output of choicebox sample app:

[image: output of choicebox sample app]

Also consider a [ComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) for such an implementation, as it has a mechanisms built into it to abstract the values of nodes from the display of the nodes (via a [CellFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#cellFactoryProperty)).  Use of a `ComboBox` is however often more complex than a `ChoiceBox`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another simple implementation from [forums.oracle.com](https://forums.oracle.com/message/10351588)

Create a class for key - value

```
public class KeyValuePair {
   private final String key;
   private final String value;
   public KeyValuePair(String key, String value) {
   this.key = key;
   this.value = value;
   }

  public String getKey()   {    return key;    }

  public String toString() {    return value;  }
}
```

Then create the ChoiceBox as:

```
ChoiceBox<KeyValuePair> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<KeyValuePair>();
```

Fill the elements as;

```
choiceBox .getItems().add(new KeyValuePair("1", "Active"));
```

*Hint: Retrive key-value pair from you database into an ArrayList and iterate*

To retrieve the value:

```
choiceBox.getValue().getKey();  // returns the "1"
choiceBox.getValue().toString();  // returns the "Active"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or simply do: `myChoiceBox.setConverter(myStringConverter)`, passing in an instance of your own subclass of `javafx.util.StringConverter`([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/StringConverter.html)).

Overriding the toString (and fromString) gives you full control over how your object is displayed without having to implement a `toString` in the object itself.